# Getting total amount of rows that contain parent/child categories. Confused why in_array isn't working

Tags: php, loops, foreach, categories

I have two tables I'm working with: categories and businesses. The categories table looks like this:

```
id   name               parent
1    Automotive         NULL
2    Tires              1
3    Oil Change         1
4    Home Renovations   NULL
5    Painting           4
6    Landscaping        4
7    Bathroom           4
```

Basically, any category that has parent as `NULL` is a parent. Anything that is a child of it references it's ID in the parent column. Simple.

I have businesses stored in a table, and each business has categories. The categories are stored as `json_encode` so they look like this:

```
["1","4","5","13"]
```

The user can add a subcategory without adding a parent, so some businesses only have subcategories.

If I want to get the total number of business for a parent category INCLUDING subcategories, here's what I'm doing:

```
$parent_categories = $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc')->get_where('categories', array('parent' => NULL));
$businesses = $this->db->select('category')->get('businesses');

foreach ($parent_categories->result() as $parent):
    $child_categories = $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc')->get_where('categories', array('parent' => $parent->id));

    $parentChildCategories = array();
    array_push($parentChildCategories, $parent->id);

    foreach($child_categories->result() as $child):
        array_push($parentChildCategories, $child->id);
    endforeach;
    // CONTINUED BELOW
```

At this point, if i `print_r($parentChildCategories)`, I get the following (excluding a bunch of other category arrays, just focusing on one):

```
Array ( [0] => 81 [1] => 80 )
```

So this is the parent category id as well as the child category id. This parent category only has one child, but others might have multiple. This appears to work.

Now I want to go through each businesses category field, decode the json into a PHP array (`$categories_array`), then see if the above array (`$parentChildCategories`) is in it. If it is, I echo 'yep'.

```
foreach($businesses->result() as $business):
    $categories_array = json_decode($business->category);

    if (in_array($parentChildCategories, $categories_array)):
        echo 'yep';
    endif;
endforeach;
```

The problem is, I never get 'yep'. Nothing. So I `print_r($categories_array)' and it gives me the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 81 )
```

The array values are the same as `$parentChildCategories`, but they are in different positions. So in_array doesn't see it as being in the array.

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm obviously doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you store the categories related to businesses this way? If you'd normalise your database, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.

I'd suggest creating a new table 'business_category_coupling', with 2 columns: business_id and category_id. That's basically all you'll ever need and eases maintenance dramatically.

Comment: So if I go this route, if a business had multiple categories, it would essentially have multiple rows in the category_coupling table? I was going to do this originally, but thought it would be "cleaner" to keep the categories as json. What a mistake that was.

Comment: Multiple rows for each business is very common and the best way to go. Imagine the relation between customers and orders, you wouldn't put that as json_encoded string now would you. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You have made my life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `in_array` does not work is that it checks whether the first array is an element in the second array - which, of course, it is not.  Without going through the full logic, to do your comparison, you can use `array_diff`:

```
$ad = array_diff($parentChildCategories, $categories_array);
if(count($ad)) {
    echo 'yep';
}
```

This code finds all elements from `$parentChildCategories` that are not present in `$categories_array`.  If there are none, then you output `yep`.